# Can a P6-free Graph contain the Grötzsch graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently working on a paper which contains a theorem of the form

> A ($P_6,K_3$)-free graph is ... if and only if it
> does not contain the Grötzsch-Graph as induced subgraph.

This is how the Grötzsch-Graph looks like:

[image]

I think I might be stuck on the understanding of $P_t$-free graphs. Isn't this restriction redundant? How can there be a $P_6$-free Graph that contains a Grötzsch-Graph, since the Grötzsch-Graph already contains paths of length $6$?

Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a path of length six, but an *induced* path of length six. In other words, you must find six vertices such that when you take the subgraph induced by them, that's a $P_6$. Informally, you must be careful with neighbors. For example, $\{6,7,8,9,5,0\}$ from your figure does not induce a path since 5 and 6 are adjacent.